# How to alter system on AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

I need to run

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET track_activity_query_size = 16384;
```

So I can see the contents of some long running queries (I can only see the beginning at the default size), but when I try to do that in pgAdmin on my RDS instance I get the error

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command
```

How do I run that alter system query?

Comment: Which part of the error message seems unclear?

Comment: @mustaccio I understand the error message. I just don't know how to run a command as the superuser in RDS. I'll try out detzu's answer when I get home!

Answer (score 12):

The RDS Postgres instance has a parameter group. Check in RDS colsole what parameter group is defined: RDS -> Databases -> choose your db -> Configuration -> parameter group. If it's the default one, create a new one and change `track_activity_query_size` to the value you need. Apply the new parameter group or change the actual one. The parameter is static so a restart is needed in any case.

Check this link for more details, please: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html